# The restored capacity of a battery

Tags: batteries

I'm reading the datasheet of the G54/3 battery from Saft [data sheet here](https://www.vri-gmbh.de/PDF/G_543.pdf). On page 2 the manufacturer show the plot 'restored capacity vs current and temperature'. But I don't really understand what the manufacturer means by the 'restored capacity'. Could anyone please explain what the 'restored capacity' is? Is it different from the capacity of a battery at certain temperature and certain (constant) discharge rate?

Comment: That is a bit strange. But I'd guess it is the energy you get out at that temperature and current, just like you suspect. Because it shows what you'd expect. Loss of capacity with lower temperature and higher current.

Comment: Lost in translation. I'd expect that words like Achieved / "returned" / "actually provided" / real-world-results - are what they are saying. ie the cell is nominally 5Ah at stated conditions (25 hour discharge rate, 20C ambient, 2V end of discharge pint) BUT if you discharge it faster (or slower) and/or at a different temperature or using a different end point voltage then Your AmpHourage WILL Vary. Bottom graph on page 2 shows that at eg 20C you get 5Ah at 100 mA discharge rate,  about 4.9 Ah at 500 mA, ~=4.6Ah at 1A, & ~=4.2 Ah at 2A. These are the restored/achieved/predicted/... capacities.

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone please explain what the 'restored capacity' is?
>   Is it different from the capacity of a battery at certain temperature and certain (constant) discharge rate?

No. Probably.

It is very likely a matter of "Lost in translation".
I'd expect that words like "achieved" / "returned" / "actually provided" / "real-world-results" / ...  - are what they are saying.
ie the cell is nominally 5Ah at stated conditions
(25 hour discharge rate, 20C ambient, 2V end of discharge point) BUT if you discharge it faster (or slower) and/or at a different temperature or using a different end point voltage then Your AmpHourage WILL Vary.

The bottom graph on page 2 shows that at eg 20C you get
5Ah at 100 mA discharge rate,
~= 4.9 Ah at 500 mA,
~=4.6Ah at 1A, &
~=4.2 Ah at 2A.

These are the restored/achieved/predicted/... capacities.

Comment: As stated on page 1...

Answer (score 0):

“Is it different ....”.  yes it varies

> The capacity **restored** by the cell varies according to current drain, temperature and cut-off).

(Above Snipped from the original page 1 which I cannot find as the product no longer exists)

This means the capacity does not **just** depend on the discharge rate but the **actual charge parameters used as well.**

5.0 Ah is the rated capacity based on specs for the above conditions.

Comment: The datasheet link was broken (for me anyway) so I replaced it. It seems that the "restored capacity" Is the actual Ah returned under various specified conditions. so "No" does not seem correct. I'm not sure that your answer adds anything useful to my 2017 one.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  I had found the original link which used the words "restored" capacity. but your link is a Darlington transistor, Now I find other datasheets with different adjectives, "Nominal" capacity 2008, It seems they had changed it.  Now I can't find the link ...(:

Comment: Doh - wrong link :-) . Thanks for that. I've changed it to the correct one. They do indeed use the word "restored" twice in the datasheet in that context. It seems to be mainly Saft who use it and not always. I suspect there may be an element of Geringlish in it. 
Here's the link I found https://www.vri-gmbh.de/PDF/G_543.pdf

Comment: Yes the bigger surprise is the G cell is ONLY for  primary 3V Lithium cells and the G 54/3 is 3V so it is not rechargeable and the G 54 has been removed from the SAFT website.  It does not exist.   I think their "Communications Department" has some explaining to do.

Comment: But in the context of a secondary cell, I think the words "restored capacity" has some *significance to me* **making the user responsible** for capacity.  What? you mean I have to slow down current rate if I want more capacity and if I use a bit less CV I get more  lifespan but less capacity?  How come it only lasted 150 charge cycles? This means the capacity does not just depend on the discharge rate but the **actual charge parameters used as well.**